# Totaljs Unirest

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I have a problem with TotalJs Framework and Unirest Module.

Error:
**TypeError: Object function (count){var arr=[];var self=this;var length=self.length;for(var i=0;i=count)return arr}return arr} has no method 'toLowerCase' TypeError: Object function (count){var arr=[];var self=this;var length=self.length;for(var i=0;i=count)return arr}return arr} **has no method 'toLowerCase'****

```
function view_homepage() {
    var self = this;

    var unirest = require('unirest');
    unirest.post('http://httpbin.org/post')
        .headers({ 'Accept': 'application/json' })
        .send({ "parameter": 23, "foo": "bar" })
        .end(function (response) {
            console.log(response.body);
        });



    self.view('homepage');
}
```

But i don't understand this error because with sails.js it works fine.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use a built-in function:

```
function view_homepage() {
   var self = this;

   Utils.request('http://httpbin.org/post', ['post', 'json'], { parameter: 23, foo: 'bar' }, function(err, response, status, headers) {
       console.log(err, response);
   });

   self.view('homepage');
}
```

**Documentation:**

> http://docs.totaljs.com/v1.7.x/en.html#api~FrameworkUtils~Utils.request